# grep regex return substring but exclude comments

Tags: regex, grep

I want to get a substring from a file, but only from lines which are not preceded by an exclamation mark (which is the comment symbol in Fortran). I would prefer to use grep (but not bound to). For example:

infile.txt:

```
calib_ss/baseline.txt
!calib_ss/base_sharpe.txt
```

Desired result:

```
baseline
```

I got this far:

```
grep -Po "(?<=/)[^/.]*(?=\.)" infile.txt
```

which returns

```
baseline
base_sharpe
```

To exclude the lines starting with ! I thought of combining the expression with

```
^[^\!]
```

but I don't manage. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This grep should work:

```
grep -Po '^[^!].*?(?<=/)\K[^/.]*(?=\.)' infile.txt
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
baseline
```

**Explanation:**

- `^[^!]` will make sure to match anything but `!` at line start
- `\K` will make sure to reset the start